# Resizable contenteditable from bottom/top

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a simple editable headline and paragraph which have height limitation. the headline input text field must be bottom aligned which means it should resize itself from bottom to top upon entering text. At the same time paragraph text field resizing itself from top to the bottom. I don't know how to do the make it resize itself from bottom/top. Here is the html code:

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true" style="max-height:70px;overflow:hidden;">
This is a headline</h1>
<p contenteditable="true" style="max-height:70px;overflow:hidden;">
This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Your question here is...?

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do the bottom and top alignment @justDan

Comment: I don't know how to do the bottom and top alignment @JeremyThille

Comment: you are using max-height, so there is no need for alignment as the height will always fit the text as long as it fits within 70px.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal yes now I understood! thnx buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Fairly easy to do with Flexbox :

```css
.container {
  border: #008000 solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container h1,
.container p {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container h1 {
  border: #f00 solid 2px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.container p {
  border: #00f solid 2px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 contenteditable="true">Type more stuff in here</h1>
  <p contenteditable="true">Type more stuff in here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, exactly! Thank you and sorry if my question was not clear at first, I am very new here @Jeremy Thille

Comment: No problem, I admit it's not easy to explain. You're welcome, glad I could help :)